# What is the purpose of the word let inside a catch expression?

Tags: swift, syntax, keyword

In the book "the swift programming language" in the beginning, they have the following example

```
func makeASandwich() throws {
    // ...
}

do {
    try makeASandwich()
    eatASandwich()
} catch SandwichError.outOfCleanDishes {
    washDishes()
} catch SandwichError.missingIngredients(let ingredients) {
    buyGroceries(ingredients)
}
```

What I'm wondering is the line

```
catch SandwichError.missingIngredients(let ingredients)
```

Specifically the syntax `(let ingredients)`

To me it looks like they are using the word let in a function call, but maybe  I'm mistaken. In any case I would like to know what the purpose of word let is there.

Comment: Please read [Enumeration - Associated Values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148) in the Swift Language Guide, actually read the entire guide. It's worth it.

Comment: Read this [Error Handling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) and [Pattern Matching in Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1008-pattern-matching-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks vadian. That was exactly my difficulty here. I did not understand Enumeration - Associated Values. Once I've read the text you've linked to, everything became clear.

Comment: I have edited the title (and tags), please check if that still reflects your intention.

Comment: @Martin R Much better :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a “value binding pattern” (inside an “enumeration case pattern”).

`SandwichError` is an enumeration with “associated values”, something like

```
enum SandwichError: Error {
     case outOfCleanDishes
     case missingIngredients([String])
}
```

Each `catch` keyword is followed by a pattern, and if an `SandwichError.missingIngredients` error is thrown with

```
throw SandwichError.missingIngredients(["Salt", "Pepper"])
```

then

```
catch SandwichError.missingIngredients(let ingredients)
```

matches and the local variable `ingredients` is bound to the associated value `["Salt", "Pepper"]` for the catch block.

It works essentially as for [Matching Enumeration Values with a Switch Statement](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID147):

> You can check the different barcode types using a switch statement, similar to the example in Matching Enumeration Values with a Switch Statement. This time, however, the associated values are extracted as part of the switch statement. You extract each associated value as a constant (with the let prefix) or a variable (with the var prefix) for use within the switch case’s body

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `let` keyword is used to create a constant variable.

In this context `let` keyword is used to create a local constant `ingredients`, which is used to accommodate the expected input parameters that is thrown as error.

In this example, whatever `ingredients` that are found to be missing, will be thrown, and the `catch SandwichError.missingIngredients(let ingredients)` will receive them inside `ingredients`, for handling the error.

Comment: So if I had not used the word let, that is if I only use catch SandwichError.missingIngredients(ingredients), would then a local variable called ingredients be accomodated. Or would it be a syntax error and would I be forced to  write something like SandwichError.missingIngredients( var ingredients)?

Comment: @BobUeland, try relating it with a normal variable declaration and initialization. `catch SandwichError.missingIngredients(ingredients)` doesn't declare `ingredients`, and compiler will not know what that is. We NEED to declare what that is. Answering your second question, if you use `var ingredients`, you'll get a warning if you don't mutate `ingredients` at all. So, using 'let ingredients` makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerations in swift can specify associated values of any type to be stored along with each different case value

```
enum SandwichError: Error {
     case outOfCleanDishes
     case missingIngredients([String])// associated value
}
```

When Matching Enumeration Values with a Switch Statement
Extract each associated value as a constant (with the let prefix) or a variable (with the var prefix) for use within the switch case’s body

```
var error = SandwichError.missingIngredients(["a", "b"])

switch productBarcode {
case . outOfCleanDishes:
    print("Out of clean dishes!")
case . missingIngredients(let ingredients):
    print("Missing \(ingredients)")
}
```